# Django - Use variables from included template

Tags: html, django, templates, include

I have the following setup:

base.html

```
...
    {% block main-content %}
    {% endblock main-content %}
...
```

admin.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block main-content %}
    {% include users.html %}
{% endblock main-content %}
```

The file users.html uses tags like '{{ users }}' because it renders from a view that also returns several variables. Right now, if I call admin.html I can see the template of users.html (basic html, css) without the variables. I don't think the template is rendering from my views.py.

Is there anyway I can obtain the variables that the view is returning?

Note: base.html and admin.html are in the same django app, while users.html is in a different one.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to pass all required variables to template and included templates from the view. If you are asking for debug purpose, use _debug toolbar_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a common misapprehension.

Templates do not belong to views. The only relationship is that a view may (or may not) render a template: but a template itself may be rendered by one or many views, and has no actual knowledge of any of them. So when you "include" your template inside your admin template, there is *no* relationship to any other view that might also render it; if you need some variables in that view, you'll need to pass them there yourself.

Note that this sort of thing - that is, including a template along with some specific context variables - is usually best handled as an [inclusion tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)